# How can I find unique substrings

Tags: python, algorithm, compression, encode

Given a binary string, how can I traverse through the str to find unique substrings. I want to add these substrings to a dictionary as the value. The key being the index, starting from 1. The substring should be divided into substrings by the first and shortest substring. I believe the logic would be something like:

1. Look at the first bit, if it's not in the dictionary as a unique substring, add it. This is always the case for the first bit.
2. Now look at the second bit. If it's not in the dictionary as a unique substring, add it. If it is, look at the second and third bit together. Is this new string in the dict of unique substrings? If not, add it. If it is, look at the second, third, and fourth bit together. And so on.

For example, given the string `"1010100"`

1. '1' is not in the dictionary, add it. `{1: '1'}`
2. '0' is not in the dictionary, add it. `{1: '1', 2: '0'}`
3. '1' is in the dictionary, so add the next bit. '10' is not in the dictionary, add it. `{1: '1', 2: '0', 3: '10'}`
4. '1' is in the dictionary, so add the next bit. '10' is in the dictionary, so add the next bit. '100' is not in the dictionary, add it. `{1: '1', 2: '0', 3: '10', 4: '100'}`

This is how the string is 'divided': |1|0|10|100|

Also, the case where `"00"` is the given binary string does not need to be accounted for.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: should we ignore "0" wherever repeated occurrence? Seems u had ignored index 3 value "0" in your explanation. What are scenarios have to be ignore?

Comment: Emm... What is stopping you from literal implementation of this algorithm? Are there any pitfalls?

Comment: I'm just not sure how to code this. I'm a relatively new programmer

Answer (score 0):

> *"... Given a binary string, how can I traverse through the str to find unique substrings. I want to add these substrings to a dictionary as the value. The key being the index, starting from 1. The substring should be divided into substrings by the first and shortest substring. ..."*

Here is an example.

Utilize a double-*for-loop* to resolve starting and ending indices for a *sub-string* value, of *s*.

Determine if the value is within the dictionary, *d*.
I'm using the *[itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)* *function*, to flatten the values list.

```py
import itertools as it
n, t = len(s := '1010100'), ''
d = {}
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i, n):
        t = s[i:j + 1]
        if not len(d.values()) or t not in list(it.chain(*d.values())):
            d.setdefault(i + 1, []).append(t)
```

Output

```
{1: ['1', '10', '101', '1010', '10101', '101010', '1010100'],
 2: ['0', '01', '010', '0101', '01010', '010100'],
 3: ['10100'],
 4: ['0100'],
 5: ['100'],
 6: ['00']}
```

Comment: The correct output for the string '1010100' should be ```{1: '1', 2: '0', 3: '10', 4: '100'}```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another example without a double nested for loop:

```
def findUniqueSubstrings(binaryString):
    uniqueSubstrings = {}
    index = 1
    currString = ""
    for i in range(0,len(binaryString)):
        currString += binaryString[i]

        if not currString in uniqueSubstrings.values():
            uniqueSubstrings[index] = currString
            currString = ""
            index+= 1

    return uniqueSubstrings
```

Comment: This doesn't work

Comment: Apologies, I accidentally moved the return line into the for loop when pasting it to stack overflow. Its fixed now

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's try:

```
def split_distinct(s):
    i = 0
    j = 1
    n = len(s)
    strs = set()
    res = []
    while i < n:
        while j<=n and s[i:j] in strs:
            j += 1
        if j<n or not(s[i:j] in strs):
            res.append(s[i:j])
        strs.add(s[i:j])
        i = j
        j = i + 1
    return res

print(*split_distinct("1010100"))
print(*split_distinct("11011010011110"))

1 0 10 100
1 10 11 0 100 111
```

I don't treat "00" because don't know clear rules for it (what about "110110100001", "110110100000001"?)

Answer (score 0):

So this is how I think we can implement this:

- Example 1

[image]

- Example 2

[image]

Code

```
def split_distinct(s: str) -> int:
    result = []
    i, n = 0, len(s)
    duplicate_at_end = False
    while i < n:
        if duplicate_at_end:
            duplicate_at_end = False
        else:
            j = i+1
        while j<=n and s[i:j] in result:
            j += 1
        if j > n:
            if s[i:] not in result:
                result.append(s[i:])
                break
            j = i + 1
            i -= len(result[-1])
            result.pop(-1)
            duplicate_at_end = True
        else:
            result.append(s[i:j])
            i = j
    return result
```

Some examples:

[image]